# How can I add new dates to existing DATE_TIME column using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to add new dates to my existing column (and set values of other columns corresponding to my new dates as NaN).
What I've tried:

```
new_dates = pd.date_range(start='18-06-2020 00:00', end='28-06-2020 00:00', freq="15min")
df1['DATE_TIME'] = df1['DATE_TIME'] + new_dates
```

and i get error = ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (961,) (68778,)

Apart from adding dates, I also have to set NaN for other rows corresponding to my new dates.
DATE_TIME is existing column.

Comment: So it sounds like you are trying to add dates to a preexisting date-column and then the new dates just need to have NaN values associated with that index?  I would recommend looking into pd.reindex(). https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html

Comment: If you scroll down in the documentation there is an example fairly similar to what you describe.